# How do I implement configuration screen in a iOS app using Swift?

Tags: ios

I'm new in developing iOS apps and I would like to know how can I implement views that appear only on first launch were the user can select his/her own language and nickname before starting the app?
I try using navigation controller in my storyboard but no positive respond.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add a new `UIViewController` to your storyboard.
2. Open identity inspector and fill the **Storyboard ID** like this:
   [image]
3. Add this code to your main `ViewController.swift` file:

   ```
   override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
       super.viewDidAppear(animated)

       let alreadyLogged = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("loggedIn")
       if !alreadyLogged {
           let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
           let configCtrl = sb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("configScreen")
           presentViewController(configCtrl, animated: true, completion: nil)
       }
   }
   ```
4. When user finished the setup, do this:

   ```
   func finishedSetup() {
       NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "loggedIn")
       dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
   }
   ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do I need to use the navigation controller? Or can I apply this without a navigation controller?

Comment: @Melchior you can apply without it.